# Vaadin chart datetime is different

Tags: javascript, polymer, vaadin-charts

I am Korean. Do not speak English well.
I want to solve the current problem.
 to represent the time. However, this time is different by 9 hours.
I want to solve this problem.  Please tell me how.
Thank you...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el9q7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edgV1.png)

```html
<dom-module id="queue-area-charts">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto id="AjaxPost" url="http://localhost:9090/ybTest2"   method="POST" content-type="application/json" handle-as="json" on-response="_onResponse" last-response="{{hresponse}}"  debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{hresponse}}" as="hresponse">
            {{hresponse.cpu}}
            {{hresponse.AGENT_TIME}}
            <p></p>
        </template>

        <vaadin-area-chart id="chart">
            <x-axis type="datetime"></x-axis>
            <y-axis allow-decimals='false' min='0' max="100">
            </y-axis>
                                    <!--"2017-07-27 18:04:46"   15  ====    1501146197000-->
            <tooltip formatter="function () {
                    return '<b>'+Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>';}">
            </tooltip>
            <data-series name="Queue">
                <data>
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{hresponse}}" as="hresponse">
                        <point>
                            <x>[[hresponse.AGENT_TIME]]</x>
                            <y>[[hresponse.cpu]]</y>
                        </point>
                    </template>
                </data>
            </data-series>
        </vaadin-area-chart>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "queue-area-charts",
            properties: {
                hresponse:{
                    type: Object,
                    notify:true,
                },
            },
            _onResponse: function(e, request) {
                this.attached();
            },
            attached: function () {
                this.async(function () {
                    var starttime = "2017-07-27 18:04:46",
                        endtime = "2017-07-28 00:00:00";
                    var oData = {"starttime": starttime, "endtime": endtime};
                    this.$.AjaxPost.body = JSON.stringify(oData);
                    this.$.AjaxPost.generateRequest();
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Post the code for ybTest2. How are you posting it to database?

Comment: //Entity

    @Id// primary key
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)//자동증가
    @Column(name ="SEQ_NO")
    public long seqNo;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern  = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name ="INPUT_TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date inputTime;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern  = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @Column(name ="AGENT_TIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull

Comment: @Ofisora
   //@ResponseBody
    public List<YbEntity> ybTest2(@RequestBody Map<Object, Object> map,Model model,Date starttime,Date endtime) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String testtime = map.get("starttime").toString();
        String testtime1 = map.get("endtime").toString();
        //testtime = 2017-07-27 18:04:46
        SimpleDateFormat transFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Comment: starttime = transFormat.parse(testtime);
        endtime = transFormat.parse(testtime1);
        System.out.print(starttime);
        List<YbEntity> YangDatas = epoService.findByinputTimeBetween(starttime,endtime);
        model.addAttribute(YangDatas);
        return YangDatas;
    }

Sorry I do not know how to add the source separately.

Once you've commented out the date format you received and the datetime you received.

Comment: @Ofisora  could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9 hours sounds exactly like Korea time zone, KST (UTC +9), vaadin-charts and its underlying chart library shows dates in UTC by default.

So you can:

- either set UTC dates to the series
- or disable the use of UTC by running the following snippet before the chart is drawn:

`Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });`

Comment: Thanks for your help.